# ReactJS project on Android WebView, Image not showing

Tags: reactjs, android-webview, react-router

I am currently experimenting on a hybrid app using ReactJS for my front-end loaded inside an Android WebView. On one of the pages, I have a list that loads an external/hosted image. Tapping on these images routes to another page that shows its description (using react-router. history=hashHistory).

Testing on the browser(chrome), the images appear once loaded. On the other hand, testing on the actual device, the images does not appear. Only when I tap the list item and press back (hashHistory.goBack) that it appears.

I know this is not the best use for ReactJS, but this is better than what we are currently using. Also, our current setup prevents us from pursuing the React Native way. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
here's a screen cap:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is only a caching issue.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @M.ImranMamda, i didn't, i discontinued this experiment since there is already React Native for Native mobile applications. This might also be the cause for the lack of answers for this question.

Comment: too bad :(, anyway I found the solution for my issue, it was due to some security issue that a relative path was not working within Android Webview, so I applied a function on all image calls that uses `file:///android_asset/static/` in the start of the image urls... thus the images started to show up!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your websettings in your code.

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```